# Left Outer Join and Substring_Index in Doctrine

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am trying to convert a mysql query into doctrine within symfony2.

Here is the mysql Query straight.

```
SELECT * FROM referrals r
INNER JOIN domain d ON LOWER(d.domain) = LOWER(SUBSTRING_INDEX(r.email, '@', -1))
LEFT OUTER JOIN user_referrals ur ON ur.referral_id = r.referral_id AND ur.user_id = 1
WHERE LOWER(d.domain) = LOWER('Gmail.com') AND ur.referral_id IS NULL
ORDER BY r.suggestion_count ASC LIMIT 5;
```

Here is my conversion into doctrine.

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $query = $em->createQuery(
            'Select r From FuelFormBundle:Referrals r
            INNER JOIN FuelFormBundle:Domain d WITH d.domain = LOWER(SUBSTRING_INDEX(r.email, "@", -1))
            LEFT OUTER JOIN FuelFormBundle:UserReferrals ur WITH ur.referral_id = r.referral_id AND ur.user_id = :userId
            WHERE LOWER(d.domain) = LOWER(:domain) AND ur.referral_id IS NULL
            ORDER BY r.suggestion_count ASC'
        )->setParameters(array(
                'domain', $domain['email'],
                'userId' => $currentUserId))
            ->setMaxResults(5);

        $referral = $query->getResult();
```

The error message I am getting when running this is.

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 110: Error: Expected known function, got 'SUBSTRING_INDEX'
```

Stack trace is

```
1 error
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\EventListener\SessionListener::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\FragmentListener::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelRequest".
INFO - Matched route "ajax_get_five_emails" (parameters: "_controller": "Fuel\FormBundle\Controller\DatabaseController::getFiveEmailsWithSameDomainAction", "_route": "ajax_get_five_emails")
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\EventListener\RequestListener::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ErrorsLoggerListener::injectLogger".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ErrorsLoggerListener::injectLogger".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\DataCollector\RouterDataCollector::onKernelController".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Acme\DemoBundle\EventListener\ControllerListener::onKernelController".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DataCollector\RequestDataCollector::onKernelController".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ControllerListener::onKernelController".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ParamConverterListener::onKernelController".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\TemplateListener::onKernelController".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.exception" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelException".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.exception" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ExceptionListener::onKernelException".
CRITICAL - Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException: "[Syntax Error] line 0, col 110: Error: Expected known function, got 'SUBSTRING_INDEX'" at /vagrant/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/QueryException.php line 44
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\EventListener\SessionListener::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\FragmentListener::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\EventListener\RequestListener::onKernelRequest".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ErrorsLoggerListener::injectLogger".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ErrorsLoggerListener::injectLogger".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\DataCollector\RouterDataCollector::onKernelController".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Acme\DemoBundle\EventListener\ControllerListener::onKernelController".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DataCollector\RequestDataCollector::onKernelController".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ControllerListener::onKernelController".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ParamConverterListener::onKernelController".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\TemplateListener::onKernelController".
```

I was going to try to use query builder however I can't seem to find how to do a Left Outer Join and the same problem with Substring_index.

Any ideas?

---

EDIT:

I have replaced `substring_index` with `LOWER(SUBSTRING(r.email, LOCATE('@', r.email ,1)))` and it looks like its accepting the syntax so far.

---

EDIT 2:

The last answer is pretty close but I am just a little off.  the answer was `LOWER(SUBSTRING(r.email, LOCATE('@', r.email)+1))`

If I figure out the issue with `LEFT OUTER JOIN` I'll post it up.
I did find this

> Fetch Joins: In addition to the uses of regular joins: Used to fetch
>   related entities and include them in the hydrated result of a query.
>
> There is no special DQL keyword that distinguishes a regular join from
>   a fetch join. A join (be it an inner or outer join) becomes a “fetch
>   join” as soon as fields of the joined entity appear in the SELECT part
>   of the DQL query outside of an aggregate function. Otherwise its a
>   “regular join”.

but I have no more time to dedicate to it.

Here's the link for the quote above http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#dql-functions

Comment: The error message is about `SUBSTRING_INDEX`, why do you think this has something to do with `LEFT OUTER JOIN`?

Comment: Did you see the last part of the question?  I would like to find a solution to both so I can use the Query Builder.  I realize that substring_index is currently the issue however if I am going to ask a question why not address both.